# Send a second order confirmation email for a specific product

Tags: orders, email, order-confirmation

It has been a while since I have worked on a Magento site. But I'm fairly certain this functionality might already be included somewhere, or there might be a free extension to achieve it.

The store has started to sell custom branded clothes for businesses where they can put the company logo on shirts etc.

What they need is for a second email to be sent to the customer if they order one of these products, simply just saying "Please reply to this email with your logo attached".

The second email will be coming from a different address. So normal order confirmation would be from sales@example.com, and the logo one would come from design@example.com

What would be the best way to achieve this? 
(Site is CE 1.6.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Magento following **event** defined on **./app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php::1115** where you would get order object as a parameter

```
sales_order_place_after
```

config.xml of your custom module should look similar to...

```
<!-- config.xml global section -->
<sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
        <custom_observer>
            <class>custommdoule/observer</class>
            <method>sendSecondEmail</method>
        </custom_observer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

There you can check for the specific product in the order items, if available execute your mail sending logic.